# Need to Inflate Expandable list view automatically without clicking on parent view

Tags: android, xml

I am new to android. I need to inflate the child of expandable list view automatically without clicking on parent view. I have searched many web sites I dont find any single clue to work like this.

```
public class ExpListActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {

    private ExpandableListView mExpList;
    private ExpListAdapter mExpListAdapter;

    final String mArrGroupelements[] = {""};
    final String mArrChildelements[][] = { { "Sachin Tendulkar", "Raina", "Dhoni", "Yuvi" } };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activitt_explist);

        mExpList = getExpandableListView();
        mExpListAdapter = new ExpListAdapter(this, mArrGroupelements, mArrChildelements);


    }
    public void onClick(View v){

        mExpList.setAdapter(mExpListAdapter);

    }

}


public class ExpListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    String[] mArrGroupelements;
    String[][] mArrChildelements;

    public ExpListAdapter(Context context, String[] mArrGroupelements, String[][] mArrChildelements) {
        mContext = context;
        this.mArrGroupelements = mArrGroupelements;
        this.mArrChildelements = mArrChildelements;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return mArrGroupelements.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return mArrChildelements[groupPosition].length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            tv = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent, null);
        }
        tv.setText(mArrGroupelements[groupPosition]);
        convertView = tv;
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView;
//      tv.setWidth(100);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            tv = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_cell, null);
        }
        tv.setText(mArrChildelements[groupPosition][childPosition]);
        convertView = tv;
        tv.setWidth(100);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use `mExpList.expandGroup(i)` for a particular group to expand or you can place it in a `for` loop to expand all the Groups

Comment: can u give me sample code.where i need to place the loop plz

Answer (score 1):

change your `onCreate` to following

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activitt_explist);

        mExpList = getExpandableListView();
        mExpListAdapter = new ExpListAdapter(this, mArrGroupelements, mArrChildelements);
        for(int i=0; i>mArrGroupelements.length; i++){
                 mExpList.expandGroup(i);
         }
    }
```

Comment: but when i click on button it showing the parent and when i click on parent then showing child.but i made parent as null.now when i click on button it should load child directly not parent.plz